# Remote BLOB Storage Filestream Issue

Tags: sql-server, remote-blob-storage

I had to enable Remote Blob Storage on my farm. I'm following this tutorial:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx#enable

And also this one:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=174

I use administrator account to Enable Filestream:

DBProperties-> Advanced -> Filestream AccessLevel -> FullAccessEnabled

I restart the SQL Server Instance,but when I try to execute:

```
use [WSS_Content_Blob] 

if not exists (select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name =  '##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##')create master key encryption by password = N'Admin Key Password !2#4' 

use [WSS_Content_Blob] 

if not exists (select groupname from sysfilegroups where groupname=N'RBSFilestreamProvider')alter database [WSS_Content_Blob] 

add filegroup RBSFilestreamProvider contains filestream 

use [WSS_Content_Blob] 

alter database [WSS_Content_Blob] add file (name = RBSFilestreamFile, filename = 'c:\Blobstore') to filegroup RBSFilestreamProvider
```

It tolds me that the Filestream service is not enables... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You cannot enable FILESTREAM on a 32-bit version of SQL Server running on a 64-bit OS

Please go over the steps for enabling FILESTREAM, maybe you missed a step.

This is how I would enable FILESTREAM for SQL Server 2008 R2:

1. On the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. In the list of services, right-click SQL Server Services, and then click Open.
3. In the SQL Server Configuration Manager snap-in, locate the instance of SQL Server on which you want to enable FILESTREAM.
4. Right-click the instance, and then click Properties.
5. In the SQL Server Properties dialog box, click the FILESTREAM tab.
6. Select the Enable FILESTREAM for Transact-SQL access check box.
7. (Optional, you can enable later if you need FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access) If you want to read and write FILESTREAM data from Windows, click Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access. Enter the name of the Windows share in the Windows Share Name box.
8. (Optional, you can enable later if you need FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access) If remote clients must access the FILESTREAM data that is stored on this share, select Allow remote clients to have streaming access to FILESTREAM data.
9. Click Apply.
10. In SQL Server Management Studio, click New Query to display the Query Editor.
11. In Query Editor, enter the following Transact-SQL code:

    To enable FILESTREAM for T-SQL access only:

    EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 1;
    RECONFIGURE

    To enable FILESTREAM for both T-SQL access and for file I/O streaming access:

    EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2;
     RECONFIGURE
12. Click Execute.
13. Restart the SQL Server service.